# how to put the result of JS/HTML page in table format?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created JS/Html page for survey but i want to show the result of survey page in table format after clicking submit button. Right now it is not coming as a table format, the answer is coming section-wise. I want one final answer which come as a table format showing result of individual section and total of both the section. Thanks in advance

Js File :

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
let section1Total = 0
let section2Total = 0
let section1Question = 0
let section2Question = 0
let section1Res = document.querySelector('.section-1-results')
let section2Res = document.querySelector('.section-2-results')
let result1 = ''
let result2 = ''

//Section 1
section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
  if (radio.checked) {
   section2Question++
   section1Total += +radio.value
  }
 })

//Section 2
section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
  if (radio.checked) {
    section1Question++
    section2Total += +radio.value
  }
 })

//Section 1
result1 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
result1 += "Total: " + section1Total + "<br>"
result1 += "Percentage: " + ((section1Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
section1Res.innerHTML = result1

 //Section 2
result2 += "<b>Results:</b><br>"
result2 += "Total: " + section2Total + "<br>"
result2 += "Percentage: " + ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
 section2Res.innerHTML = result2

}
```

Html Page :

```html
<p>
Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

<h2>Section 1</h2>
question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<br>
<div class="section-1-results"></div>

<div class="section-2">

 <h2>Section 2</h2>
 question 1:
 <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
 <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
 <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

 <br> question 2:
 <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
 <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
 <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
 <br> question 3:
 <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
 <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
 <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
 <br> question 4:
 <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
 <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
 <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
  </div>
 <br>

 <div class="section-2-results"></div>

 <br>

 <button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
   Submit
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a dynamic `table` in your JS function which `returns` an each table of `results` from each section.

I **believe** you want one `final` answer of `each` `section` with results showing at the bottom of it.

I have also added some **validation** to make sure that user must select `atleast` one question for each section so that the tables are not `empty` all the time. It will show user an error `message` if question is selected from `each` section.

Instead of using two `results` div i am only using one `final-results` where each `section` results table will be `displayed` for you in a table format.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {

  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section'
  }

}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"

  return result
}
```

```css
table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="final-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Where to add(which file) table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: @jugal Hi, you need to these styles in your `.css` file. Its CSS you need to add.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let section1Res = document.querySelector('.section-1-results')
  let section2Res = document.querySelector('.section-2-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 1
  section1Res.innerHTML = generateResultTable(section1Question, section1Total)

  //Section 2
  section2Res.innerHTML = generateResultTable(section2Question, section2Total)
}

function generateResultTable(checkedQuestion, total) {
  var result = "<b>Results:</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (checkedQuestion * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"

  return result
}
```

```css
table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<br>
<div class="section-1-results"></div>

<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="section-2-results"></div>
<br>

<div class="section-total-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
   Submit
  </button>
```

I encapsulated a method to generate a table, you only need to pass in two parameters: the number of selected questions and the total number of questions